# React Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve, How to compile with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am dealing with an issue on two new projects I have just started and I have it configured the way I have it on another in production and for some reason I can't seem to find the bug here.

I have started my react project with the latest version of `create-react-app` using: `npx create-react-app myapp` and for some reason my app does not compile locally with `react-router-dom`.

Here are my dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
```

I have an `index.js` file where I am wrapping my `<App />` component inside of the `<Router />` component that I am importing with `BrowserRouter` as specified from `react-router-dom`.

Here are the contents of my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

From there my `<App />` component implements a custom `<Routes />` component that uses `Route` and `Switch` from `react-router-dom` to handle my app's routing needs.

Here are the contents of my `<App />` component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import Routes from "./Routes.js";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <Navbar fluid collapsOnSelect>
          ...... misc navbar code
        </Navbar>
        <Routes />
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is what my `Routes.js` file looks like and how it uses the `Route` and `Switch` from `react-router-dom`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./containers/Home";

export default () => <Switch>
                       <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
                     </Switch>;
```

Here is the `{ Home }` component that I am trying to serve up locally:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Home.css";

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <div className="LandingPage">
          ... random html code
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

And finally here is the error:

[image: React Fails to Compile]

What do you think could be the problem here??? Thanks !

**UPDATE: Adding File Hierarchy**

[image: Project Hierarchy]

Comment: Could you tell us your file hierarchy? Where your different files are in relation to each other.

Comment: maybe it should be `import Home from "containers/Home";` (remove the './')

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey I updated it with an image of the project file structure for you and thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @Ted I tried that and its a no-go. That didn't work. The containers directory is in another folder in the project... See update for a better reference. Thanks!

Comment: Move the `containers` folder into the `src` folder

Comment: Yeah, now that you added the structure, it's clear where the problem is

Comment: @ted sorry about that! I totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! So it was with the file hierarchy. `Routes.js` is in `src`, so it's looking in `src/components`, which doesn't exist.

Instead, make it `import Home from "../containers/Home";`, or restructure the project so that `containers` is inside `src`.

Comment: I knew it was something ridiculous. Let me try that now to make sure and Ill mark it as the answer. Thanks for adding another set of eyes on this. I wish it would've been a more significant problem!!! smh

Answer (score 1):

Your routes.js should be

```
import Home from "../containers/Home";
```

You gotta go up one directory to get to where containers is, the way you have it set up looks for containers inside there src

Comment: I went ahead and just moved the directory into /src thank you!